# How to mock a downstream method call?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have an issue where I have some code like

```
public void a() { 
    Obj1 one = Obj1();
    Obj2 two = Obj2();
    one.b();
    two.c();
}
```

I'm trying to call the `a()` method, and I would like the `b()` method to execute but I would like to mock out the `c()` method.

What is the best way to do this, since `Obj2 two` gets declared within `a()`?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- you rework your design to become easier to test. For example by getting rid of that that `new Obj2()` call. Instead, you could pass a **factory** for Obj2 objects to that class; and use that. The factory returns mocked objects; you are fine. Or you look into other mechanisms for **dependency injection**.
- you turn to PowerMock(ito) which allows for mocking calls to `new`; as outlined [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor) for example.

My personal two cent: I recommend to go for option 1 - it is always better to improve the design; instead of using the big (ugly) PowerMock hammer to "fix" design problems. So, a simple example would like:

```
public class EnclosingClass {
  private final Obj2Factory factory;
  EnclosingClass(Obj2Factory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
  }
 void a() {
   Ob2 two = factory.make();
 }
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how you would use a factory to solve this issue? i'm not clear on how it would help.

Comment: -1 For a) the unnecessary denigration of PowerMock, and b) the unjustified assumption that the occurrence of `new Obj2()` is bad design (AFAIK, this is perfectly fine in OO programming, and OO is still considered good design...).

Comment: Maybe you tell that the people that waste their time with dependency injection frameworks. Because if you say that *new* isnt a problem then that part of the industry that spends so much time avoiding that very thing could stop wasting their time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example test, using the JMockit library (which I develop):

```
@Test
public void exampleTest(@Mocked Obj2 anyObj2) {
    new A().a();

    // In case we want to check two.c() was called:
    new Verifications() {{ anyObj2.c(); }};
}
```